air-lld:1:1 symbol(s) not found after upgrading to XCode 16
I'm attempting to build my project after upgrading to XCode 16 and am having trouble getting it to compile. When I attempt to build the project I get an error: air-lld:1:1 symbol(s) not found for target 'air64_v24-apple-ios15.0.0-simulator'.
I am able to get my project to compile by setting the metal language revision property to 3.2, but this causes other issues for older devices. Ideally I should be able to build using the default for the deployment target option.
I'm using CoreImage metal kernels with both [[stitchable]] kernels and extern c kernels as a fallback for devices that don't support metal 2.4. The code used to compile the extern c kernels is taken straight from the wwdc video from 2020, and the stitchable kernels merely need the -framework CoreImage flag set.
Any advice for how I can get the project to compile would be greatly appreciated!

As far as I can tell apple has broken CoreImage in xcode 16. I seem to have found a solution by linking against the older version of coreimage.metallib and including it in the app bundle. It's about 45kb, so not the end of the world, but it'd be nice if it wasn't needed.
So find the coreimage folder inside of xcode 15 frameworks folder (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage) and then place it inside the root of your project. I created a folder called Frameworks and placed it in there. The only file you need to keep in there is the coreimage.metallib file, you can delete everything else. The file structure should look like YourProject/Frameworks/CoreImage/coreimage.metallib
Then in the build settings under "Other metal linker flags" add the following two lines, where the 2nd line is the path to the folder containing your copied CoreImage folder.
-F
./Frameworks

By any chance, is this issue fixed in XCode 16.1 RC? Also to download older version of CoreImage framework, one needs to have XCode 15 installed.

I'm unsure, but it would be nice if so! And yes you need an older version of xcode to find the working coreimage binary

I do not have enough disk space to download either XCode 15 or XCode 16.1 RC unfortunately to do anything.

Is this still an issue with the new Xcode? For our extern C kernels we don't see this issue. But we also don't yet have [[ stitchable ]] kernels.

I haven't updated yet, but I'll report back once I do.

@FrankRupprecht I checked with XCode 16.1 and the issue still persists with stitchable kernels. Apple suggests to move back to extern C kernels as a workaround but that's an unnecessary mammoth change as there are hundreds of kernels.

Tested on Xcode 16.2 RC, still has the same error. One workaround is to set the Metal Language Revision to 3.2.
However, this version was introduced with iOS 18, and it's strange that it still works on iOS 17 devices. I don't know if it has any side effects.
Or copy the Xcode 15 framework. However, as the framework is from iOS 17, by doing the steps from @aferriss, you'll lose new iOS 18 Core Image API. I also collect the Xcode 15 files here, so you don't need to download it again.
